# Cannot read unzipped qgs project file

Tags: qgis, error, windows-11

I saved my project as .qgz file in 3.22.14 Bialowieza version on Windows 11.

When I tried to open it the next day I got the following error message:
[image]

I restored an older version of the file, saved it under a different name, went on with my work and saved it before closing my computer at the end of the day. But this morning when I tried to open it again I got the same error message.

The biggest problem for me is not recovering the work that I have done so far because I have my restored version that I am still able to open. But how do I make sure it doesn't happen again? I don't want to have to redo all the work every day.

I didn't have the autosaver plugin before, but I have installed it now.
And I tried opening the file with 3.28 Firenze version but no success either.

Comment: Doing a `save as` may help, as it tends to remove obsolete content from previous QGIS versions.

Comment: For curiosity, you could rename the working and problematic project files to `.zip`, unzip and look at the file content at line 9085. It may point to whatever generated the issue.

Comment: Thanks! I found the problem. It was a file that contained a column with weird symbols.